# Which security patches should i install every month for SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, security, cumulative-update

In SharePoint 2013 which security patches should i install every month and i don't want to install all Cumulative updates every month because of size also one reason.
like for example Aug 2020

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4484485/august-11-2020-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2013

Description of the security update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013: August 11, 2020 (KB4484479)
Description of the security update for SharePoint Foundation 2013: August 11, 2020 (KB4484487)
Description of the security update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013: August 11, 2020 (KB4484478)
Description of the security update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013: August 11, 2020 (KB4484183)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just install the Cumulative Updates, instead. CUs are primarily a collection of security hotfixes month-to-month for SharePoint 2013, now. I recommend CUs over individual hotfixes as there have been issues with hotfix dependencies causing things to break if you didn't apply the correct ones, or newer hotfixes depending on a previous hotfix, etc.

CUs are just easier to manage.

Comment: Hi Trevor thanks but CUS large in size it will not cause any issues every month if i install CU ?

Comment: CUs only apply the files that require an update but it makes sure _all_ files are up to date.

Comment: Every month if install CUS is  database sizes will go larger SharePoint_Config,Service App databases and Content dbs ?

Comment: In general, no.

Comment: Hi trevor recently i my server was windows patched and i saw all Aug2020 Sharepoint security patches installed with windows patching , so can i run again sharepoint config wizard ? and no need to install seperately Aug 2020 CU?